# как сложить две переменные с числами в pyside

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Работа проходит в функции def push(self):
Мне нужно сложить две переменные: a и b получить переменную с результатом rez и вывести rez в переменную v.
Но у меня получается только сложить переменные как текст а нужно как число как мне это сделать
Код :

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 391)
        Dialog.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("QDialog{\n"
                             "background:#434542;\n"
                             "}")
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 60, 61, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                      "background: #282928;\n"
                                      " border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;\n"
                                      " border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                      "border-color: #7ad442;\n"
                                      "color:#ffffff;\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                      "background: #ffffff;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 281, 131))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("QTextBrowser {\n"
                                       "background: #434542;\n"
                                       "border: 3px solid #7ad442;\n"
                                       "\n"
                                       "}")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 340, 281, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Univers Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
                                   "background:#282928;\n"
                                   "border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;\n"
                                   " border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                   "border-color: #7ad442;\n"
                                   "color:#ffffff;\n"
                                   "}")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 281, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
                                    "\n"
                                    " background: #282928;\n"
                                    " border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;\n"
                                    " border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                    "border-color: #7ad442;\n"
                                    " color:#ffffff;\n"
                                    "}\n"
                                    "")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 201, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
                                 "color: #ffffff;\n"
                                 "}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 201, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
                                   "color: #ffffff;\n"
                                   "}")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 281, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      " background: #282928;\n"
                                      " border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;\n"
                                      " border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                      "border-color: #7ad442;\n"
                                      " color:#ffffff;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "QTextEdit: hover {\n"
                                      "backgroung:#ffffff\n"
                                      "}")
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 256, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.textBrowser_2.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser_2.setStyleSheet("QTextBrowser {\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         " background: #282928;\n"
                                         " border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;\n"
                                         " border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                         "border-color: #7ad442;\n"
                                         " color:#ffffff;\n"
                                         "}\n"
                                         "")
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "OK", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog",
                                                              "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                                              "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                                              "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                                              "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Century Gothic\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                                              "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:14pt; color:#39ff6a;\">ИМТ      &gt;18       ниже нормы </span></p>\n"
                                                              "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:14pt; color:#39ff6a;\">ИМТ      &gt;18       ниже нормы</span></p>\n"
                                                              "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:14pt; color:#39ff6a;\">ИМТ      &gt;18       ниже нормы</span></p>\n"
                                                              "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:14pt; color:#39ff6a;\">ИМТ      &gt;18       ниже нормы</span></p>\n"
                                                              "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:14pt; color:#39ff6a;\">ИМТ      &gt;18       ниже нормы</span></p></body></html>",
                                                              None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(
            QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "ИМТ - Индекс массы тела", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(
            QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Введите свой рост в см:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_3.setText(
            QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Введите свой вес в кг:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog",
                                                                "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                                                "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                                                "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                                                "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                                                "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Ваш ИМТ = </p></body></html>",
                                                                None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


class MainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.push)

    def push(self):
        a = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        b = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        rez = str(int(a)) + str(int(b))
        v = self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(rez)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Получилось только так , а нужно чтобы числа складывались.

[image: получилось только так]

Comment: `str(int(a) + int(b))`?

Comment: `rez = str(int(a) + int(b))`

Comment: Спасибо dlmon и Clark Devlin

Comment: мне показалось, что этот вопрос мы уже решили в предыдущем вашем вопросе?

Comment: Блин туплю, а эту переменную как правильно записать: `rez = str(int(b/pow(a, 2)) * int(10000)) `

Comment: кстати, вы уже задали много вопросов, но почему-то ни один не отмечен как имеющий правильное решение. Я не проверял, но наверняка там есть достойные решения, предложенные вам. Вы должны как-то реагировать на ответы, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: `rez = str(int(b) / pow(int(a), 2) * 10000)`

Comment: @S.Nick Спасибо. Не подскажите ли статью в которой можно узнать то что я у вас спрашивал

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/python-data-types/ ,  https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python , ...